# jQuery's localtime plugin failed while loading content via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using PHP & MySQL along with AJAX & jQuery to show contents from my database table.

PHP: serverside language as usual.
jQuery: to convert UTC time to local time based on user location. Thanks to jQuery localtime plugin :)
AJAX: to show contents of page2 into page1 on selecting a value from a drop down menu

Total no of pages: 2

Page1.php

I have an HTML table to which I show contents of all users. One of the values fetched from database is a UTC datetime variable.
To convert it into user's local time, I simply used a jQuery plugin. All that I had to do was add

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.localtime-0.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">$.localtime.setFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");</script>
```

the above given files & then add a span `<span class="localtime"> </span>` in my table & echo the datetime variable into it. Viola! UTC time is now converted into user's local time.

In that same page, I have a dropdown menu showing list of all users from my database table. ANd on the onchange property of the drop down menu, I have called an AJAX function. This function will pass the username to page2.php & database opertaions are done in page2.php & results corresponding to that user is calculated & shown into an HTML table similar like to the HTML table I have in page1.php.

But in this table, UTC remains as such even though I tried adding the jQuery files in that page also. Why the jQuery localtime plugin didn't convert UTC time in page2 to localtime when it did the same in page1???

Here are two screen shots.

**Page 1 before AJAX content loaded**

[image]

**Page1 after AJAX content loaded**

[image]

**Page1**:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Converting UTC time to Local time</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.localtime-0.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">$.localtime.setFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");</script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
    function value_pass_func(uname)
    {
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()//callback fn
        {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
               document.getElementById("showtable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","page2.php?variable="+uname,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','dummydb') or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$query="SELECT distinct(user) FROM pagination ORDER BY id ASC";
$res    =   mysqli_query($connection,$query);
$count  =   mysqli_num_rows($res);
?>
</br>
</br>
</br>
<select id="ddl" name="ddl list" onchange="value_pass_func(this.value);">
    <option selected value="">select any</option>
<?php
if($count>0)
{
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    $now=$row['user'];
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $now; ?>"><?php echo $now; ?></option>
<?php
}
}
?>
</select>
</br>
</br>
<?php
$query1="SELECT * FROM pagination ORDER BY id ASC";
$res1    =   mysqli_query($connection,$query1);
$count1  =   mysqli_num_rows($res1);
if($count1>0)
{
?>
<div id="showtable">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-striped" border="1">
        <thead>
        <tr >
            <th>id</th>
            <th>post</th>
            <th>user</th>
            <th>now</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($res1))
        {
            $idd=$row1['id'];
            $post=$row1['post'];
            $username=$row1['user'];
            $datetime=$row1['now'];
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $idd; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $post; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $username; ?></td>
                <td><span class="localtime"> <?php echo $datetime; ?></span></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page2**:

```
<?php
$un=$_GET["variable"];
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','dummydb') or die(mysqli_error($connection));

$query="SELECT * FROM pagination where user='".$un."' ORDER BY id ASC";
$res    =   mysqli_query($connection,$query);
$count  =   mysqli_num_rows($res);
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.localtime-0.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">$.localtime.setFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");</script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-striped" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr >
        <th>id</th>
        <th>post</th>
        <th>user</th>
        <th>now</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
   {
       $idd=$row['id'];
       $post=$row['post'];
       $username=$row['user'];
       $datetime=$row['now'];
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $idd; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $post; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $username; ?></td>
        <td><span class="localtime"> <?php echo $datetime; ?></span></td>
    </tr>
<?php
   }
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're loading jquery.. so I advise you to use it

The most simple answer to your question is to run this after your innerHTML replacement:

```
$.localtime.format(".localtime");
```

This will evaluate all of the elements again.

I suggest you do the following:

1. Use jquery's AJAX ([link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)) to GET your table data.
2. Deliver your table data using JSON ([link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)).
3. Personally I prefer to use Moment.js ([link](http://momentjs.com/docs/)) to format my dates.

A basic jquery example..

Scripts on page1:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.localtime-0.5.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>

    $.localtime.setFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    function value_pass_func(uname)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "page2.php",
            data: { variable: uname },
            dataType: html
        }).done(function(data) {
            $("#showtable").innerHTML = data;
            $.localtime.format(".localtime");
        });
    }
</script>
```

And drop those script tags in page2.

I haven't tested that localtime script but it probably does it's thing when fired

Comment: Sorry. It does not do it's thing when fired. localtime script now produces error. Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. OR TypeError: $.localtime.format is not a function @Tiele Declercq